ошибка при попытке поймать вебхук от телеграма 400 Bad Request
технология проста: зарегистрировал урл-вебхука и ожидаю по этому адресу ловить все запросы от телеграма, которые от будет отправлять при написании сообщений боту. он и отправляет запросы, как я вижу из отчёта
  {
      "ok": true,
      "result": {
        "url": "https://mysite.com/webhook/telegram?secret=Zk37wG9tQvXy",
        "has_custom_certificate": false,
        "pending_update_count": 20,
        "last_error_date": 1714440368,
        "last_error_message": "Wrong response from the webhook: 400 Bad Request",
        "max_connections": 40,
        "ip_address": "185.68.166.164"
      }
    }

но я их не могу поймать в силу ошибки 400 Bad Request. Как это полечить?

на отдельной странице создал вручную html форму с action "webhook/telegram" и отправляю данные. Они тоже не доходят и ошибка 400. Я понял, что это вопрос с csrf токеном. Это мой yii2 отказывается принимать запросы без токена.  Можно тупо отключть через поведения или beforAction для этого actio. Или как по умному сделать?
